# Fluid Sim is not being emmited

Tags: fluid-simulation

Whenever I try to add any type of liquid or smoke simulation the object set to inflow doesn't emit anything i tried changing the setting for both the inflow and domain.Could it be due to my hardware as i don't have a powerful system.Plz help. My computer specs are:Graphics - GT710, RAM - 4GB, CPU - i3 6100 @3.70 GHz.

Comment: Curious, have you tried creating a very simple scene with just an inflow and domain?

Comment: yes i have just doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on what the inflow object is, if it's flat you need to check "is planar" and add some surface emission, also if the object is smaller then the voxel size, which is represented by the cube inside the domain, it may not emit particles

Comment: i used a uv sphere as the emitter and also increased its size above the voxel size still doesn't work.